# Add sequence to each element of a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector as indicated below

```
x <- c(1,32,60,86,115,142,171,198)
```

I would like to create a sequence as seq(x[i],x[i]+2,by=1)  for each element of the vector. The resulting vector should be

1,2,3,32,33,34,60,61,62,86,87,88.....

I was wondering if there is a function similar to rep to do this? Appreciate your input on this.

Answer (score 8):

We can use the vectorized `rep`

```
rep(x, each = 3) + 0:2
#[1]   1   2   3  32  33  34  60  61  62  86  87  88 115 116 117 142 143
#[18] 144 171 172 173 198 199 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `saaply` to loop over every element of `x` and generate a `seq`uence of numbers and combine them with `c`

```
c(sapply(x, function(x) seq(x, x+2)))

# [1]   1   2   3  32  33  34  60  61  62  86  87  88 115 116 117 142 143 144 171 172 173 
#       198 199 200
```